# search data using jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I want to search record in sql server database and then show it in the web page using jsp. How can I do this please help me. My code is also given bellow. 
Thanks

```
<%
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","root","root");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test where firstName = ?");
        while (rs.next()){
            %>
          <tr bgcolor="#Abc">
            <td> <%=rs.getString("firstName")%> </td>
             <td><%=rs.getString("lastname")%></td> 
    </tr>
      <%
        }
     }catch (Exception ex){
       System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    %>
```

Comment: What is the issue with this code?

Comment: @Pablo the query, in particular the predicate

Comment: It is showing only the heading of the table like FirstName and Password. Not showing the saved data from database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the 'first name' that you want to query on.

Assuming it's passed as a parameter in the URL (`http://localhost/myapp/mypage.jsp?firstName=Nick`), this should do the trick:

```
<%

  Connection connection = null;
  PreparedStatement statement = null;
  ResultSet resultSet = null;

  try 
  {      
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","root","root");

    statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT firstName, lastName FROM test WHERE firstName = ?");
    statement.setString(1, request.getParameter("firstName"));

    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(); 

    while (resultSet.next())
    {
%>

<tr>
  <td><%= resultSet.getString(1) %></td>
  <td><%= resultSet.getString(2) %></td> 
</tr>

<%
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    if (resultSet != null) result.close();
    if (statement != null) statement.close();
    if (connection != null) connection.close();  
  }
%>
```

Note:

- using a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) protects against [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-prepared-statements-can-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks).
- you haven't needed to load the driver with a [Class.forName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()) since the [service provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider) mechanism was introduced.
- it's considerably more efficient to 'get' from a [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) by index.
- you should always be releasing database resources in a `finally` block.
- you should really use a connection pool rather than connecting directly to the database from a JSP.

Comment: Thanks for help. I have add your code in my project but it still not showing the data from the database.my code is given bellow please explain if it have any error. thanks

Comment: I have add the given code to my project but it is still not working. Means not showing the data from database. Please help me out.

Comment: Most IDEs will debug JSPs but if you have trouble getting that working, then add some debug logging after the connection is made, after the query is run and in the event of an `Exception`.  If you're not seeing errors then you should check your database contains the data you're expecting to see

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to ever be setting what the parameter should be, denoted by ?.  I'd expect a setString call on a preparedStatement.  Consider [this example](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077706/core-java/named-parameters-for-preparedstatement.html) on how to use JDBC.  This isn't as much as JSP issue, rather the parameter isn't set in the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using `java.sql.Statement` so automatically this goes wrong

```
stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test WHERE firstName = ?");
```

as you dint set the firstName anywhere you can use something like

```
stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test WHERE firstName = '"+name+"'");
```

or use java.sql.PreparedStatement
You can accomplish the task like :

```
PreparedStatement statement = connectionObject.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM test WHERE firstName = ?");

statement.setString(parameterIndex, String firstName);
```